# Some recently changed resources are not yet published

Tags: java, eclipse, google-app-engine

Every once in a while i get this error message. If I click Yes then my GAE server starts but with old code. I've tried cleaning, restarting eclipse, shutting down computer, closing and opening the project again, deleting the launch config and adding it again but nothing works. Does anyone know what causes this issue?

[image]

Answer (score 8):

If that happens for whatever reasons, you need to re-publish the changes you made to your project; otherwise, the server will run with the app previously published from the old code.

Open the *Servers* view (*Window* > *Show View* > *Servers*). The status of your server will read, for example, "[Stopped, Republish]". Right-click on the server, and click *Publish*. Then the status will go into "[Stopped, Synchronized]".

Comment: @code511788465541441, if you consider Chanseok's answer helpful for you, please consider accepting it. Thank you.